# I can not connect ODBC in google colab

Tags: odbc, google-colaboratory, pyodbc

I am trying connect ODBC with Colab, but it is give me a error. The error is OperationalError: ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Could someone help me?

Let you my code

> %%sh
> curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
> curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get -q -y install msodbcsql17

> !pip install pyodbc
>
> import pyodbc
>
> Parámetros de conexiòn a SQL
>
> server   = 'server-training.database.windows.net'
> database = 'db_axm'
> username = 'axm_reader'
> password = 'careerp@th22*'
> conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};'
> 'SERVER='+ server +';'
> 'DATABASE='+ database +';'
> 'UID='+ username +';'
> 'PWD='+ password)`

I have benn triying change the code with some alternatives but I have been unsuccessful

Comment: Does the credentials are valid?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/prod.list >
#-----------------
change url version 16.04 to 18.04

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help